# Cloud Foundry app logs error on success

Tags: flask, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I'm getting this error in my bluemix logs allot.

```
[APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX - - [date] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

What does it mean? It seems to indicate that i'm getting a 200 response and the actual site works, but why is this showing up as an error?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had asked that myself some time ago and then wrote a [blog entry about it](http://blog.4loeser.net/2017/10/cloud-foundry-logging-sources-deciphered.html). Basically the `ERR` denotes that the information is coming from `stderr`. An `OUT` means the source is `stdout`.
It cloud be that your app and its modules are configured to write the output to `stderr` and thus you see it.